# Removing a prefix with ren command doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, command

I'm only a beginner at batch programming, so this question might be really simple.

The command is `ren -* *`; I want to rename all files starting with a dash; for example,
`-spec.txt` to `spec.txt`.

However it doesn't work! Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that is not how the REN command interprets wildcards ;-)

If you want to know how it works, then have a look at [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090).

Unfortunately, you cannot use a simple REN command to remove the leading `-`. You will need to write and use a short batch script instead. Something like the following will do the trick. I toggle delayed expansion on and off to avoid problems with `!` in file names.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (-*) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!file!" "!file:~1!"
  endlocal
)
```

If you know that your file names never contain `!`, then the script can be as simple as:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (-*) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  ren "!file!" "!file:~1!"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (command line, for batch script double the `%` to `%%`):

```
for /f "delims=-" %i in ('dir /b /a-d -*') do if not exist "%i" rename "-%i" "%i"
```

The code renames the file only if no file with this name already exists to avoid error messages.